# Adding UInt64 in array without "\( )" gives unexpected value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uint64

Adding UInt64 in array without "( )" gives unexpected value

```
    var arr : Any[] = []
    var no : UInt64 = 9971989999
    arr.append(no)
    println(arr)
```

While with "( )" gives correct value

```
    var arr : Any[] = []
    var no : UInt64 = 9971989999
    arr.append("\(no)")
    println(arr)
```

Why?

Comment: I'm not sure it will affect the code but using names like `no` for an integer is confusing as hell to read. Also, what is your output for the two `println` statements? You've told us it doesn't work but you haven't said what it is doing.

Comment: Either I need to take a far closer look at Swift or those two snippets do entirely different things (the first appends the value of the integer called `no`, the second appends a string that happens to look similar to the variable name `no` if you squint). Please clarify your question, for example by giving the expected and actual output.

Comment: @delnan Ah yes, the syntax `"\(var)"` uses the String parsing to create a string from the variable.

Comment: Your code produces the correct result `[9971989999]` when I compile and run it in a 64-bit iOS Simulator. In a 32-bit Simulator I get `[237764688]` as output. So this looks like (another) bug in the Swift compiler or runtime.

Comment: Any chance of actually putting the unexpected value in the question?

Comment: @MartinR seems to have found the key issue here. Be sure to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) so Apple can fix it — you can probably help by testing on 32 vs 64 bit devices to note whether it's a device or simulator issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Its a Swift bug.
You can report it to Apple.
Its Working in 64-bit iOS but not in 32-bit iOS.

Generally there is no need to change `println(arr) into println("\(arr)")` for printing such values and You convert int into string by use of `"\()"` while saving to array.